# Python 3.5 32 & 64 bit -- Scipy & Tensorflow issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, scipy, 64-bit

I'm trying to install Python 3.5 both 32 & 64 bit and also be able to transfer between the two as needed, but am not having any luck. Scipy will only install when I use the 32bit (Various issues when trying to install 64bit version even with physical .whl files).

Meanwhile Tensorflow only works on x64.

I'm using windows 7, and have tried various solutions I've found on Stackoverflow, but have had no luck.

Also, was thinking of just dual installing linux mint and running python off there. Would any of you recommend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Anaconda or similar for the installation? - if this is an option in your case I would highly recommend it under Windows.

Comment: I have tried installing Anaconda, have had no luck there either. Scipy shows it is installed, but will not actual work when called upon

Answer (score 0):

Installing Linux (highly recommended)

While your Issue with Scipy & Tensorflow.
Why don't you use the Anaconda Installer for Windows x64 bit(it contains alomost all major packges for Data Science already(Scipy too)) ,  and then install Tensorflow

Comment: I've tried Anaconda multiple times and still does not work; Scipy is installed but the package is not able to import.

Comment: @vlepore can you please copy you Error Stack while working with Scipy. I'll suggest remove all python and then Install this https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.3.1-Windows-x86_64.exe and then install Tensorflow through Conda Shell

Comment: This does not work as well. Tensorflow only works on 3.5 build, and I continue getting scipy and numpy errors when running a script that imports both numpy and scipy ("Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed. Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. Reinstall numpy") -- I've reinstalled both scipy and numpy multiple times with no luck, and the script runs on my laptop with no issues so it cannot be the script...